# I need to print Null if there are no unique elements in an Array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hash, hashmap

I need a program that prints only the unique elements of an Array, OR, if there are no unique elements, it prints "Null".
My code already can find the unique elements and print it, but it's printing Null for each repeated ones too. I need to print just one "Null" if there are no unique numbers, or just the unique elements (which is working already for that).
The example below, it should print 3 (the non repeated element), and if you put another 3 in the list, should print Null one time only (which I can't figure out how).
I appreciate the help in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int IDs[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5 };

        int items = IDs.length;

        uniqueIDs(IDs, items);

    }

    static void uniqueIDs(int IDs[], int items) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {

            if (hash.containsKey(IDs[i])) {

                hash.put(IDs[i], hash.get(IDs[i]) + 1);

            }

            else {

                hash.put(IDs[i], 1);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> uniqueIDs : hash.entrySet())

            if (uniqueIDs.getValue() == 1)

                System.out.print(uniqueIDs.getKey() + "\n");
        
            else {
                System.out.println("null");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first loop in your method you should add this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int IDs[] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3, 5};

    int items = IDs.length;

    uniqueIDs(IDs, items);

}

static void uniqueIDs(int IDs[], int items) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) {

        if (hash.containsKey(IDs[i])) {

            hash.put(IDs[i], hash.get(IDs[i]) + 1);

        } else {

            hash.put(IDs[i], 1);
        }
    }

    boolean flag = false; //We assume we don't have unique elements
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> uniqueIDs : hash.entrySet()) {
        if (uniqueIDs.getValue() == 1) {
            flag = true;//Now we have at least one unique element
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> uniqueIDs : hash.entrySet()) {
            if (uniqueIDs.getValue() == 1) {
                System.out.print(uniqueIDs.getKey() + "\n");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

//Output:

```
null
```

Also: a more general advice, in complex codes add the {} because sometimes it gets really hard to understand where a code block starts or ends for someone else trying to read your code, or even yourself sometimes!

Comment: I just replaced your code on my Eclipse ( I could use Spring too, no problem), but it's not working properly. Please, I hope I'm not doing anything wrong, but If you delete the last part of my code (the "else" part) it will work perfectly, printing number 3, but I need to print Null (one time only) if I put another 3 in the list for example.

Comment: I've already upvoted and put as "best answer", I appreciate the help if you can see what is wrong in there!

Comment: But you said you only want to print null once... Can you describe the problem a bit further? As it is now it will print all unique numbers (only 3 in your case) but will print null only if there are no unique numbers. I will update the answer with the full code to make clear what the new code will be

Comment: My original code, without the last part with the "Else" for printing "null" is working properly to print only unique numbers ( which is one of the functions I need in this program), so, on that list, if there is only one number 3, it should print 3 without anything else, just number 3. But, if I put another number 3, the list won't have any unique numbers, only repeated numbers, so the program should print just one "Null" and nothing else. I managed only to print the unique numbers together with null (and it's prnting null for each repeated number, which I don't want it)

Comment: Plz copy and paste the code in the answer. I added the output with the number 3 two times and it is the one you want

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much! I can see where I was wrong now!